# How to execute functions with delay, underscorejs/lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

### Background

I have a JavaScript function that prints numbers to the screen. This function prints a lot of numbers, but I am using a screen as old as [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) so it can't print the numbers so fast!

The solution? Throtlle/debounce/delay the prints using [`underscorejs`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4).

### Tentative

My first tentative was to use `throttle`.

```js
let fun = num => {
  console.log(num);
};

let throttleFun = _.throttle(fun, 1000);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  throttleFun(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

But instead of printing all the numbers with a 1000ms of separation, it just calls the function every 1000ms, which causes it to only actually execute twice.

My next try, was to use `debounce`:

```js
let fun = num => {
  console.log(num);
};

let debouncedFn = _.debounce(fun, 1000);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  debouncedFn(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Now, again, instead of printing the values with 1000ms of separation, debounce actually delays the execution of my function since it last executed by 1000ms, which causes it to only execute once.

### Question

All the behaviors I previously mentioned are documented, and they are the same for both underscore and lodash.

My question here is:

- Using one of the previous libraries (or another similar one), is there a way to print **the arguments the function receives** in the console with 1000ms of separation between them, using a similar function style?

Please note that while in this case the arguments happen to be numbers, in reality they can be strings, objects or any other thing without any co-relation whatsoever.

Comment: did you look at [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) ?

Comment: Yes, and I fail to see how it would be of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the native setInterval function:

```
let fun = num => {
  console.log(num);
};

let max = 10, i = 0;

let timer = setInterval(() => {
  fun(i);
  i++;
  if (i === max) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

If you want to use a underscore/lodash, you do do something like so:

```
let fun = num => {
  console.log(num);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    _.delay(fun, 1000 * (i + 1), i);
}
```

Comment: So basically, if I want this to work outside a for loop I need to have a list of functions, which I will later on execute. Right?

Comment: Yes. the `cancelInterval` will help you cancel it whenever you want. But make sure you have the handle for the `setInterval` function

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Yes, you need to increment the delay for each of the functions, otherwise they'll all just run at the same time, with a delay.