# Why is my promise returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

## Background

I am trying to make a function that delays the execution of asynchronous functions by X ms.

For the purposes of this demonstration, the following is the async function, which takes an URL:

```
/*
 *  This is a simulation of an async function. Be imaginative! 
 */
let asyncMock = function(url) {
    return new Promise(fulfil => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            fulfil({
                url,
                data: "banana"
            });
        }, 10000);

    });
};
```

## Objective

My objective here is to have a function, that will take the `url` argument of `asyncMock` and then call it every X ms or until there are no more arguments left.

Basically, I want every invocation of `asyncMock` to be separated by X ms.

As an example, imagine I call `asyncMock` 20 times in a row. Normally, those 20 calls would be done immediately. What I want, it to make sure that there is Xms of delay between each of the 20 calls.

## Tentative

My idea to solve this, is to have a factory, that will return a [promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) that will execute the function after X ms.

```
let throttleFactory = function(args) {

    let {
        throttleMs
    } = args;

    let promise = Promise.resolve();

    let throttleAsync = function(url) {

        return promise.then(() => {

            setTimeout(anUrl => {
                return new Promise( fulfil => {
                    fulfil(asyncMock(anUrl));
                });
            }, throttleMs, url);
        });
    };

    return Object.freeze({
        throttleAsync
    });
};
```

Ideally I would use this factory like in the example bellow:

```
let throttleFuns = throttleFactory({
    throttleMs: 2000
});

console.log('running');

throttleFuns.throttleAsync('http://www.bananas.pt')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

throttleFuns.throttleAsync('http://www.fruits.es')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

throttleFuns.throttleAsync('http://www.veggies.com')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
// a ton of other calls in random places in code
```

## Problem

The problem here is that my `throttleAsync` fucntion outputs `undefined` three times immediately. I believe this might be because I am not defining `promise` properly.

## Question

How can I fix this code to work as intended?

Comment: Aside from the promise issues, I don't see how this *throttles* anything. It delays things, but it doesn't throttle them.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I should change the description? I'm on it.

Comment: Updated description, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `throttleAsync` returns the result of calling `promise.then`, and the `then` callback doesn't return anything. This makes the promise created by `then` resolve with the value `undefined`.

You probably meant to have it return the new promise you're creating, but you're not doing that until the `setTimeout` callback. You want to do it prior (but there's more, keep reading):

```
let throttleAsync = function(url) {

    return promise.then(() => {
        return new Promise( fulfil => {
            setTimeout(anUrl => {
                fulfil(asyncMock(anUrl));
            }, throttleMs, url);
        });
    });
};
```

There's also no reason to pass the URL through `setTimeout` like that, so:

```
let throttleAsync = function(url) {

    return promise.then(() => {
        return new Promise( fulfil => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fulfil(asyncMock(url));
            }, throttleMs);
        });
    });
};
```

Originally I though the `promise` there was unnecessary, but you've clarified that you want to ensure that repeated calls are "spaced out" by `throttleMs`. To do that, we'd use the above, but update `promise`:

```
let throttleAsync = function(url) {

    return promise = promise.then(() => {
    //     ^^^^^^^^^
        return new Promise( fulfil => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fulfil(asyncMock(url));
            }, throttleMs);
        });
    });
};
```

This way, the next call to `asyncThrottle` will wait until the previous one has fired before starting the next.

Live Example:

```js
const throttleMs = 1000;

const asyncMock = url => url;

let promise = Promise.resolve();

let throttleAsync = function(url) {

    return promise = promise.then(() => {
    //     ^^^^^^^^^
        return new Promise( fulfil => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fulfil(asyncMock(url));
            }, throttleMs);
        });
    });
};

console.log('running');

throttleAsync('http://www.bananas.pt')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

throttleAsync('http://www.fruits.es')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

throttleAsync('http://www.veggies.com')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you are making all the calls at the same time. My objective is to make sure that each call is separated by `throttleMs`. That is why I try to pass everything to the same promise. So the `promise` object will only run the next execution after the current one ended. In your code, everything will resolve at the same time, which is not what I plan to achieve. What I want to is for each resolution to be separated by `throttleMs`. Is it more clear? Thanks for the response though!

Comment: The thing here is that i want the `then` clause to be executed with `throttleMs` delay. That is why my `setTimeout` is before the promise :D

Comment: Updated description according to your feedback, I hope it is clear now!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: If you want them spaced out, the middle solution above does that with a small change; I'll update.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Updated.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I have added +1. I don't want to be pushy here but I understand from the code (and testing I did) that in this code, the next  task will only execute after the one before has completed. So to speak, if my `asyncMock` takes 10s and the delay is 1s, if I have two calls, the second call will only be executed after 11s. My objective here, (perhaps I should remake the question?) is for the second call to be executed after 1s. Would this be possible?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: To answer that question, I have to ask: What does `asyncMock` do? Does it spend 10 seconds doing **synchronous** work? Does it start an asynchronous process that takes 10 seconds to complete? If so, what is its return value (if any)?

Comment: `asyncMock()` does some asynchronous work like making an HTTP request or writing to a large file. The idea is that `asyncMock()` will always return something in the form of a JSON object. I have edited my question with a new version of `asyncMock` !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: In the last code block above, just change `fulfil(asyncMock(url));` to `asyncMock(url); fulfil();`. That way, the throttling promises don't wait for the `asyncMock` promise, and you'll get overlapping `asyncMock` calls (but spaced out at `throttleMs` intervals).

Comment: I also thought about that, but if I do it then `delayer.delayAsync('http://www.bananas.pt')
    .then(console.log)` will always print `undefined` as the function is returning nothing. Perhaps I should take a step back and implement this with a different architecture ?

Comment: I previously attempted another solution but without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558149/throttle-batch-get-requests-to-server-javascript

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: I'm afraid at this point I just don't know what your goal is. Is your goal: 1. Ensure `asyncMock` isn't called more than once every `throttleMs`, and 2. Have `throttleAsync` return a promise that will get resolved with  `asyncMock`'s resolution (when it happens, which may be 10 seconds later)?

Comment: Ok, this is a fight for another question. In my opinion the original answer was very well explained and you my dear Sir, deserve the reward. I will mark this as solved, and attempt to explain my objective in a different question. If I am lucky you will see it :P

Comment: In case you feel like making a few more points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651439/how-to-delay-execution-of-functions-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
        setTimeout(anUrl => {
            return new Promise( fulfil => {
                fulfil(asyncMock(anUrl));
            });
        }, throttleMs, url);
```

What you're doing here is you return a promise from the setTimeout callback. The return value of functions run by setTimeout are ignored so no one will get that value.

Comment: This is it! How do I fix it so that the return values of functions processed by `setTimeout` are not ignored?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix They are always ignored. Instead of returning a new promise in setTimeout you have to resolve a promise that is already returned somewhere else where it s not ignored.