# Angular 4 - then is returning null

Tags: angular

I try to get some data from a promise, but nothing is returned. Could someone help me with this? What's  wrong??

return test is **zone_symbol__state:null
__zone_symbol__value:Array(0)__proto**:Object

```js
load(): Promise < any > {
  const test = this.http
    .get(this.translationPath)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      this.createTranslationProviders
    ).catch((err: any) => {
      Promise.resolve();
      console.log('resolve' + err)
    });
  return test; // this is always NULL 
}



private createTranslationProviders(response: Response) {
  let translationProvider: any;
  translationProvider = [
    //  { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: response },
    //  { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'de_DE'
    }
  ];
  return translationProvider;
}
```

Comment: what is that your doing? why are you converting to promise ?

Comment: `.then()` does not return a Promise. It in fact is returning nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my promise returning undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577647/why-is-my-promise-returning-undefined)

Comment: I added a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lo3IM65rOLQ7ny8bXD8J?p=preview



It's not working,yet, I'm using CLI in my project. The goal is to pass the local  provides to the APP_INITIALIZER. 
I think, I missunderstood something general. Hope some one give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your TranslationService returns a list of providers in a promise but you do not add this providers to the module. You can take a look at ng-conf translation repo how it does it without using APP_INITIALIZER but with loading list of providers and after that boostraping module with them:

https://github.com/ocombe/i18n-demo/blob/c3a063bb51d097eee14f889bce48b4bb9df9d1da/src/main.ts#L12

```
getTranslationProviders(environment.production).then((providers: 
  CompilerOptions[]) => {
   const options = { providers };
   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, options);
});
```

Also be aware that it doesn't work with AOT at this moment. You might find the following links to be helpful:

[i18n] plans for v4 and beyond -
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477

Lost in Translation (ng-conf 2017) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dihyu1a2bPc

Comment: Thanks Julia, but I'm not using system.js for reading the file. I'm wondering, how to use an the angular http request instead? How to import this in to the module export functions?

Comment: this repo uses angular-cli that also does not use systemJS but webpack. why do u think about systemJS? If you think about System.import, it is nothing to do with SystemJS but this is webpack function for loading async stuff based on standard.

Comment: Yes, cause of "System.import" - thanks for bringing light into the darkness. "System.import" wasn't working until now. System .. not find... or something else. I will check why it's not working... Do I have to include the "system" somewhere?

Comment: declare var System: any;

Comment: Ok, it's working, now - so far. But I'm wondering, for what kind of reason, this chunk files were created? I debug the code, it seems that it's reading the xlf file on lang-change. What's happen with the chunk files?

Comment: Webpack creates chunk for each asyn loaded file. Look at webpack documentation.